# Which one do you choose SFTP or FTPS

Tags: sftp, ftps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FTP v/s SFTP v/s FTPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/131240/ftp-v-s-sftp-v-s-ftps)

I want to establish a secure file transfer system, but I'm very confused about choosing between SFTP and FTP SSL.

Can you give me some suggestion and consideration why I use SFTP or FTP SSL?

Answer (score 0):

FTPs is SSL layer on top of FTP protocol.

You are connecting to ftp service port ( default 21 ) , traffic transfered is
protected with SSL.

SFTP is subsystem of SSH service.

You are connecting to ssh server ( port 22 by default ) , traffic is transfered
securely using secure channel similar to one in case with FTPs.