# Can FTP over SSL [FTPS] using IIS be configured on port 21

Tags: iis, ftp, ftps

I am trying to configure a FTPS site and have been configuring it on port 22. I need to understand if we can use port 21 for setting up FTPS [in IIS manager].

Comment: no - port 21 is used by FTP, not FTPS. Why do you want to use FTPS? Its an even more horrible protocol than FTP and given the problems you have already you are heading for a world of pain. Use SFTP.

Comment: Well, you can actually, but it's non sense. Port 22 is for SSH/SFTP, not FTPS. Those are two different protocols. See http://serverfault.com/q/131240/168875